# PropertyChanged on bound items of a ListView is null (involves Windows Workflow and ModelItems)

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4, inotifypropertychanged, propertychanged

Firstly, I'll summarise what I am doing. Then I'll present what I think to be the relevant bits of code of one of these steps exhibiting the titled-problem, and then I'll explain the problem at then end.

I am exposing an internal library for automating one of our software products to Windows Workflow, allowing engineers (not software engineers) to use our library without actually writing code, amongst other reasons. I am designing a step through which the user will select a method to use, then populate the list of input parameters via Workflow Arguments. Executing the workflow will call this method on the object at runtime (and yes, this works).

**My step logic**

```
[Designer(typeof(EntityMethodStepDesigner))]
public class EntityMethodStep : CodeActivity
{
    ...
    [Browsable(false)]
    public ObservableCollection<ArgumentWrapper> MethodArguments { get; set; }

    public EntityMethodStep()
    : base()
    {
        MethodArguments = new ObservableCollection<ArgumentWrapper>();
    }

    ....
    protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        Collection<RuntimeArgument> arguments = new Collection<RuntimeArgument>();

        foreach (ArgumentWrapper wrapper in MethodArguments)
        {
            RuntimeArgument ra = new RuntimeArgument(wrapper.MethodParameterName, wrapper.Argument.ArgumentType, wrapper.Argument.Direction, true);
            metadata.Bind(wrapper.Argument, ra);
            arguments.Add(ra);
        }

        metadata.SetArgumentsCollection(arguments);
    }
}
```

**My step view**

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="MyNamespace.Steps.EntityMethodStepDesigner"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                      xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation">

<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>

<Grid>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableEntityMethods}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntityMethod}" />

    <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Header="Parameters">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ModelItem.MethodArguments}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myNonEnumArgumentWrapperTemplate}">
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

**myNonEnumArgumentWrapperTemplate data template**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myNonEnumArgumentWrapperTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <sapv:ExpressionTextBox Expression="{Binding Path=Argument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ArgumentToExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter=In }"
                                ExpressionType="{Binding Path=ArgumentType, Converter={StaticResource ModelToObjectValueConverter}, Mode=OneWay }"
                                OwnerActivity="{Binding ModelItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type sap:ActivityDesigner}}}"
                                MaxLines="1" />

    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**My step view code**

```
public partial class EntityMethodStepDesigner : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public EntityMethodStepDesigner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AvailableEntityMethods = new ObservableCollection<MethodInfo>(); // This list is populated elsewhere, so for all intents and purposes consider this list to be populated

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MethodInfo> AvailableEntityMethods { get; set; }
    private MethodInfo _selectedEntityMethod;
    public MethodInfo SelectedEntityMethod
    {
        get { return _selectedEntityMethod; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedEntityMethod == value) return;
            _selectedEntityMethod = value;

            if (_selectedEntityMethod != null)
            {
                ModelProperty methodArguments = ModelItem.Properties["MethodArguments"];
                methodArguments.Collection.Clear();
                ParameterInfo[] parameters = _selectedEntityMethod.GetParameters();
                foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
                {
                    ArgumentWrapper wrapper = new ArgumentWrapper(parameter);
                    methodArguments.Collection.Add(wrapper);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ArgumentWrapper class**

```
[Serializable]
public class ArgumentWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ArgumentWrapper()
    {
    }

    public ArgumentWrapper(ParameterInfo methodParameter)
    {
        // Store the method direction
        if (methodParameter.IsIn && methodParameter.IsOut)
            MethodParameterDirection = ArgumentDirection.InOut;
        else if (methodParameter.IsOut)
            MethodParameterDirection = ArgumentDirection.Out;
        else
            MethodParameterDirection = ArgumentDirection.In;

        // Create an argument, with type and direction matching the input
        Type activatorType = null;
        if (methodParameter.IsIn && methodParameter.IsOut)
            activatorType = typeof(InOutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(methodParameter.ParameterType);
        else if (methodParameter.IsOut)
            activatorType = typeof(OutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(methodParameter.ParameterType);
        else
            activatorType = typeof(InArgument<>).MakeGenericType(methodParameter.ParameterType);
        Argument = (Argument)Activator.CreateInstance(activatorType);

        ArgumentType = methodParameter.ParameterType;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private Argument _argument;
    public Argument Argument
    {
        get { return _argument; }
        set
        {
            if (_argument == value) return;
            _argument = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Argument");
        }
    }

    private Type _argumentType;
    public Type ArgumentType
    {
        get { return _argumentType; }
        set
        {
            if (_argumentType == value) return;
            _argumentType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ArgumentType");
        }
    }

    public ArgumentDirection MethodParameterDirection { get; set; }

    public void ReferToEntityDirectlyByName(bool enable)
    {
        if (enable)
        {
            Argument = new InArgument<string>();
            ArgumentType = typeof(string);
        }
        else
        {
            Type activatorType;
            if (MethodParameterDirection == ArgumentDirection.InOut)
                activatorType = typeof(InOutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);
            else if (MethodParameterDirection == ArgumentDirection.Out)
                activatorType = typeof(OutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);
            else
                activatorType = typeof(InArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);
            Argument = (Argument)Activator.CreateInstance(activatorType);

            ArgumentType = MethodParameterType;
        }
    }
}
```

To bring this all together, I've taken a screenshot of this step with a method selected:

[image]

This shows a method that will be called on an object, taking 5 arguments, 3 of which are enums (the red error is because the fields are empty).

Now, the bindings almost work - the view correctly initialises, allowing me to populate the fields and execute the workflow. But the view does not update if I make changes to the *ArgumentWrapper* object.

**The problem:**
If I change *ArgumentWrapper.ArgumentType* in code, the change is not propagating to the *ExpressionTextBox*. I know this because when the *ArgumentToExpressionConverter* converts the entered expression into an argument, it always returns an argument of the type at construction, regardless of if the type has since changed. I tried implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged*, but *PropertyChanged* is null, and I've been unable to work out why.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ArgumentType` property you have this bit of code in an `else` statement:

```
Type argumentType = null;
if (MethodParameterDirection == ArgumentDirection.InOut)
    argumentType = typeof(InOutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);
else if (MethodParameterDirection == ArgumentDirection.Out)
    argumentType = typeof(OutArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);
else
    argumentType = typeof(InArgument<>).MakeGenericType(MethodParameterType);

Argument = (Argument)Activator.CreateInstance(argumentType);
```

This `argumentType` variable is not getting set to the `_argumentType` field or `ArgumentType` property. I'm not sure if that is relevant or not, but if it is, then you need to use the `_argumentType` field and call `OnPropertyChanged("ArgumentType");` at the end of the property code.

Comment: I did wonder if I needed to rename it. `argumentType` is used solely for creating `Argument`, and an example value would be `InArgument<PSMesh>`. `ArgumentType`, although named similarly, is for the type that the argument represents, so in my example it would be `PSMesh`.

Comment: I also noticed you say to call `OnPropertyChanged()`. This is my problem, the `PropertyChanged` event is null, so making this call does nothing.

Comment: Oh, that's strange... you *seem* to have implemented the interface correctly.